# get the username of who triggered pipeline job ( manually or scm trigger)

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job that gets built in two ways :

1. IF someone commits to the github repo , triggering the job.
2. IF someone manually builds the job.

within my pipeline, I need to get the name/info of person who triggered the build either directly (manually) or indirectly(SCM commit). I have the following code:

```
node('slave'){
    wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
      return BUILD_USER
    }
}
```

This gets me the name using the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin plugin.

**This works on manual but always gives SCM trigger when through SCM trigger. How do I get the name/info of the person who committed for the trigger to happen via SCM ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get $CAUSE in workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587927/how-to-get-cause-in-workflow)

Answer (score 1):

ScmTrigger does not hold information about the user who committed to git.
You can get the user who commited by using git command:

```
git log --format='%an <%ae>' GIT_COMMIT_ID
```

- %an is the author's name
- %ae is the author's email

Another option is to use a git hook that will trigger the job instead of SCM polling. in that case you can pass the commiter from the hook to the job. (for example https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github)